# Python 3 Selenium Select from drop down menu with the same ID but different value

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Firefox and want to click on the chosen text from the drop down menu.
So I have opened the optgroup and want to choose this one:

```
<option value="WSS" id="A5">[PREMIUM] WSS (wss://)</option>
```

There are different ones just with another value but the SAME ID.

I tried this one but without success:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('A5'))
select.select_by_value("WSS")
select.select_by_visible_text("visible text/the shown text on the drop down menu")
select.select_by_value('WSS')
```

Comment: what error are you getting addful slect tag

Answer (score 1):

You could try to get the parent object (with "./..") which must be "select" in the HTML code and list all the possible options. It avoids you the problem of multiple id.

Try this:

```
yourValue = "WSS"
listOptions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//option[@id='A5']/./../option")
for option in listOptions:
    if option.text == yourValue: # if wrong test "if option.get_attribute("innerText") == yourValue:"
        indexed = listOptions.index(option)
        break
Select(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//option[@id='A5']/./..]")).select_by_index(indexed)
```

I wrote it directly here, it might be wrong, don't hesitate to give your feedback with more HTML code it'll help ;)